# NewRelic - C# WCF distributed Client app talking to Server, install Agent on client machines?

Tags: c#, wcf, newrelic

We are looking at possible ways to profile / analyze user actions in our WCF app that consists of a distributed client and a central server. I'm looking at New Relic and I'm seeing that it requires a .NET Agent installed with Admin privileges to function.

Is the New Relic Agent required to be installed (with Admin privileges) on each machine running the Client app, or is it possible to include a .dll with the client app and not require Admin privileges? Is it perhaps enough to install the Agent on the Server only? Can we somehow get around the requirement of admin privileges being required on the client machines?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The .Net Agent doesn't have a dll only install option and must be installed with the proper permissions in order to function correctly.

Whether or not you need to install this on the clients really depends on what they are doing and how your application is designed.  If they are simply sending up data and not using it in a highly interactive manner then installing the agent may not get you a whole lot for the trouble of having to install another tool on a client system.

A staged approach may be best in this situation.  You could start with the server and see if that provides enough data to work from and if not test it out on a few client systems to see if that gives you more useful data.

Comment: :( Thanks for the reply, I'll see what will work for us.